# 2000 Ford Ranger 3.0L temp gauge cold

Tags: ford, coolant, temperature, ranger

Originally had bad head gaskets, replaced them and all was well.  Riding home from work a month later and gauge started dropping to cold, got home and noticed coolant leak, the water level was so low that it wasn't making contact with the sender so I added coolant and all was well again.  Coolant leak got worse and gauge read cold again so I replaced the timing cover gasket which was the coolant leak and replaced the water pump at the same time.  since then my gauge hasn't read above 'C'. I then figured maybe the stat was sticking so I replaced that still reads cold.  thought it may be defective so I returned it and got another one and it still reads cold.  Ground the sender wire and the gauge reads hot so the wiring and gauge are fine so I replaced temp sender with a BWD sender and still reads cold.  At this point Im at loss for what it could be.  The clutch fan seems to be working correctly and I don't think that would make it read below C just run a little colder than normal.  I'm getting good heat too.  Any ideas?

Comment: Buy one from Ford. Have had a lot of trouble with Borg Warner parts lately. Also be sure the engine is grounded to the battery properly.

Comment: Formatting your wall of text would help clarity.